# How to append next .csv and not all in folder

Tags: python-3.x

I want to scan the next .csv file that is created in a cron job and add it to my test.db. Right now the code that I have written replaces the entire file. If I change 'replace' to 'append' then I get the entire .csv contents of my folder appended and not the new file that was added to my folder by my cron job.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
folder = glob.glob("/Users/redacted/redacted/redacted/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in folder:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
engine = 
create_engine('sqlite:////Users/redacted/redacted/redacted/test.db')
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    frame.to_sql('csv2', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I get the results I want with this code but I am replacing the entire test.db. I want to scan the folder, see that a new .csv file has been added and select just the new file and append it to the existing database

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the simplest way to do this would be to call your python scipt as part of your cronjob (i.e. after the new csv file has been created), and then have your python script simply process the last csv file.

This requires

1. a change to your cronjob to invoke the python script
2. the following changes to your python script

---

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

filepaths = glob.glob("/Users/redacted/redacted/redacted/*.csv")
filepath = max(filepaths, key=lambda f: os.stat(f).st_ctime

li = []
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

engine = 
create_engine('sqlite:////Users/redacted/redacted/redacted/test.db')
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    frame.to_sql('csv2', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

**UPDATE**:
If you want to separately keep track of the files you've already processed, then you'll need to maintain a separate datastore:

```
configPath = 'seenFiles.txt'
with open(configPath) as infile: seen = set((line.strip() for line in infile))

filepaths = glob.glob("/Users/redacted/redacted/redacted/*.csv")
filepaths = [filepath for filepath in filepaths if filepath not in seen]
for filepath in filepaths:
    li = []
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

    engine = 
    create_engine('sqlite:////Users/redacted/redacted/redacted/test.db')
    with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
        frame.to_sql('csv2', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

with open(configPath, 'a') as outfile:
    for filepath in filepaths:
        configPath.write(filepath + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out and report back.

Comment: This worked perfectly. The only thing I will add for someone else looking at this result is that I had to "import os". Otherwise it worked exactly as you wrote it. Thank you!

Comment: Id like to change my answer, haha. This works if I am only looking for the most recent file. If I don't run the cron jobs between the creation of the .csvs' then it will only grab the most recent .csv. I want it to be able to look at the folder and say, I already have 1-5 but since I last looked, 6-9 were created and need to be added to my .db. the way the above is written it would only grab 9 and leave 6-8 out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ScreeBee: Check out the update. I've made the requested change. However, noted that per step #1, you'd run the (unedited) script every time you run your cronjob (and ONLY then). So unless your cronjob creates more than one input file, you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: So after further messing with your original post I added "for filename in folder:" back into the statement and then added "echo=False" to "create_engine('sqlite:////Users/redacted/redacted/redacted/test.db, echo=False')" and this produced the answer I was looking for.  I am still going to look at your other response. Just haven't got there yet. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I am trying to add a TimeStamp column to every new csv that is scanned and added to the .db. I am using this line of code                        "df.insert(0, 'TimeStamp', pd.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))"                  but every time it runs it changes the time stamp for every row and they are all the same. How do I make it list a new time stamp for every new .csv inserted into the .db?

Comment: That sounds like another SO post, to me. I have no idea how to make this work